# Reading a text file with Tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file, readfile

In a text file I use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to create a column-like grid, but apparently those tabs are just read as spaces, which of course breaks the formatting.

This is my code (`path` is the file path, e.g. `D:/folder/testtt.txt`):

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        while (tr.Peek() != -1)
        {
            Response.Write(tr.ReadLine() + "<br/>");
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it should appear:

[image: Screenshot]

[Link](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/w22wTGWeFqu0mvf-3iYcu7MgrPynprGdGT3Ai28xLuh2M8Px5Krj3Rclbxl6BIxXne-nmQ9NTNOhQkE=w1256-h789)

And this is how it currently appears:

[image: Screenshot]

[Link](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/D-Kwhn9vLSpnLvG9XplRe4PHb9DxSZkdCmVqROtNMIpN4jklUz5rkrCXJzcr6p1YTijQVSneG-DMnJM=w1256-h789)

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no tab entity defined in ISO-8859-1 HTML, so I think you can replace tab characters with some `&nbsp;` characters:

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        while (tr.Peek() != -1)
        {
            var htmlLine = tr.ReadLine().Replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;") + "<br/>";
            Response.Write(htmlLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you output the file contents in a `<pre>` tag? It will preserve the tabs and give you a nice monospaced output.

Comment: im newbie here, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

You can create real grid, as you are outputting HTML:

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(path))
    { 
        Response.Write("<table>");
        while (tr.Peek() != -1)
        {
            Response.Write("<tr><td>");
            Response.Write(String.Join("</td><td>", tr.ReadLine().Split('/t')));
            Response.Write("</td></tr>");
        }
        Response.Write("</table>");
    }
}
```

This will be the cleanest solution for me - you want it to look like a grid - make a grid :)

Comment: bro, ini cara ksh id di table atau tr td nya gmn ya ?